# restfb get all comments on all post since specific date

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I am trying to get all comments on all the post of a specific page since a given datetime. I am building a social media application which will monitor a facebook page activity and therefore i have to fetch all the comments on every post of that page from specific datetime. I am using restfb library for java. I am not using fql as some people are saying that facebook is about to discontinue the fql queries. So i am using the restfb methods which can do the job for me. any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to fetch all comments and filter on client side.

Facebook suggests to use realtime subscriptions. So Facebook sends you a request as soon as a new comment is added to a post. But afaik this is only working with pages you're the admin of.